# setRotation() on RecyclerView's parent causes lag

Tags: android, performance, transformation

For a pure design stuff I need to perform some animation on a RecyclerView Parent. These animations include a scale and a rotation on Y axis. When recyclerview is not populated everything is okay, but if I add some elements (not so much) animation become very laggy. I suppose because on each frame the recyclerview tries to refresh all its view even if nothing in the adapter has changed.
This is the code I use to animate the parent:

```
final float scale = 1 - 0.3f * slideOffset;
panel.setPivotX(0);
panel.setPivotY(panel.getHeight() / 2.0f);
panel.setScaleX(scale);
panel.setScaleY(scale);
float angle = -slideOffset * MAX_ROTATION_ANGLE;
panel.setRotationY(angle);
```

'panel' is my custom layout view where is located the recyclerview plus other views, 'slideOffset' is a float between 0-1 defined by user's finger on the screen.

I've tried also:`setHasStableIds(true);`to the adapter but nothing changed, and even `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);`doesn't help.